# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings is working in <title> but not for <asp:Label>

Tags: asp.net

I get value from web.config for `<title>` and `<asp:Label>`.
In case of `<title>`, It's working by `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"]`.
In case of `<asp:Label>`, It's working by `AppSettings: Key`.
Is it possible to manage code and using either `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"]` or `AppSettings: Key`?
For example: using only `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"]`.

web.config

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Title" value="My Title"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

.aspx

```
<head runat="server">
    <%--It's working--%>
    <title><%: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Title"] %></title>

    <%--It's not working--%>
    <%--Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Title' does not exist in the current context--%>
    <%--<title><%: AppSettings: Title %></title>--%>
</head>
<body>
    <%--It's not working--%>
    <%--Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.--%>
    <%--<asp:Label ID="label1" Text="<%: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Title"] %>" runat="server" />--%>

    <%--It's working--%>
    <asp:Label ID="label1" Text="<%$ AppSettings: Title %>" runat="server" />
</body>
```

Output
[image: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings is working in <title> but not for <asp:Label>]

Comment: `Text='<%# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Title"] %>'`. And put `DataBind();` in Page_Load.

Comment: @VDWWD, It's working, but can't using double quote `Text="<%# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Title"] %>"`

Comment: It doesn't work the same because the one is a server-side control that renders to html, and the other is simply markup.

Do you really need your label to be server-side, or could you replace it by a simple <span>?

Comment: It's a DataBinding Expression https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa983586(v=vs.94)

Comment: @MennovandenHeuvel, understand and thank you very much.

Comment: @VDWWD, understand and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <appSettings>
        <add key ="Name" value ="Name"/>
    </appSettings>

     <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="<%$appSettings:Name %>"></asp:Label>

     <asp:TextBox ID = "txtBox1" runat = "server" Text = "<%$appSettings:Name %>" />

     <span><%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"]%></span>
```

**This is simplest way to achieve...**

Comment: What is difference between `<span><%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"]%></span>` and `<%:ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"]%>`. There are same output.

Comment: In 1st I'm showing with namespace I.e. system.configuartion....In 2nd I'm direct referring web.config value....Both give same output